# Running Bash Script at random time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cron

I have as iperf.sh shell script in multiple sub servers that runs at every `" 1,14,28,42,50 * * * * "` and pings the iperf server to check bandwidth , is there any way to randomize this cron or setting up a shell script that sleeps and runs at random time...?

[ Note : The issue that i am facing with this classic cron system is all sub-servers are running the `iperf.s`h script at the same time and my main-Iperf server is getting high cpu utilization which is resulting to improper ping data. ]

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Perhaps have them start at a scheduled time them sleep a random amount before doing the actual work?

Comment: `1,14,28,42,50 * * * * { /bin/sleep $((RANDOM%120))  ; /path/to/your/script ; }` might work. Not sure if `cron` shells support `$(( $RANDOM ))` else (as above) put the sleep cmd at the top of your scripts. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a randomized wait period at the start of your script (or even in the crontab itself, as suggested in the comments).

I recommend GNU `shuf` which will be more portable than `$RANDOM` (since not all shells will support it, e.g. `dash` won't).

```
sleep $(shuf -i5-20 -n1)

# Rest of script
```

You can experiment with the range of random wait periods (5 to 20 seconds in this example).